# What does a "Copy/Cut & Paste" operation exactly consist of?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ntfs, copy-paste, ext

I understand the purpose of these operations. What I'd like to know is

1.What happens at the File System Level ? Does a new MFT entry for the copy get created in the
   destination volume's MFT and how is space  allocated on the destination volume for this copy ?

2.What does "Copy & Paste " exactly consist of ? My understanding of a Copy is
STEP 1 - Read a block of data that has to be copied.(What is the size of this block)
STEP 2 - Send this read block from the source volume to destination volume (How is data transferred ? 
             Is there any protocol involved or is  a pipeline setup ?)
STEP 3 - At destination , Read incoming block of data and Write to the disk.
STEP 4 - Repeat 1-3 until we reach of end of all that has to be copied.

If I had to copy a few 1000s of files, does the OS prepare a temporary list of all that has to be copied ? Also why does Windows not provide an option to either Suspend/Pause a Copy&Paste operation

Can someone please elaborate ? I'd like to know how it works on Windows as well as Linux since I need to compare the two
Finally Where does a Cut & Paste differ from Copy & Paste at File System Level ?

Comment: Hi Dhiwakar, Good question. Why do you want to compare this in Windows and Linux? Any specific reason?

Comment: No specific reason :). I'm just curious to know how it differs on Windows & Linux. It might be useful to know how ext & ntfs file systems differ.